# How to retrive date from sqlite sql query and send to calling function

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am retrieving the date column value from db(sqlite).

```
public Contacts ReadDaysLeft(int daysid)            
{               
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_Path))               
    {                  
      var data = dbConn.Query<DaysLeft>("select  * from DaysLeft where Id = " + daysid).FirstOrDefault();

      DateTime dt =  Convert.ToDateTime(data.Date);      
      return data;                
    }      
}
```

I can get date value from that sql query by 
**DateTime dt =  Convert.ToDateTime(data.Date);**

But my question is, how to send that date value to my calling function.. Please help

Comment: `data.Date` is not _already_ a `DateTime`? I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I send to calling method.?

Comment: Which method you talking about exactly? If you want to return it, why not just `return data.Date` instead and then use this return value for your _that_ method?

Comment: See, I'm calculating days left from current date and future event dates, So I am storing future event date in db. While display to user that, how many days left, I am retrieving date stored in db and subtracted with present date. So I am retrieving event details, date in above query. and displaying it in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caller:

```
DateTime dt;
var result = ReadDaysLeft(123, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt); //Is that what you need?
```

Calee:

```
public Contacts ReadDaysLeft(int daysid, out DateTime dt)            
{               
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_Path))               
    {                  
      var data = dbConn.Query<DaysLeft>("select  * from DaysLeft where Id = " + daysid).FirstOrDefault();

      dt =  Convert.ToDateTime(data.Date);      
      return data;                
    }      
}
```

For more information see: [out (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)